# Forcing Firefox to render XML in a tree like fashion

Tags: xml, firefox

I am trying to get Firefox to render the XML that is being returned to it in a tree like format as in Internet explorer.

Currently it just displays the field values .. i.e. NO XML

Is there some special setting am I missing?

EDIT

Here is the xml that is being returned

```
<ArrayOfSampleItem xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/InmoCasaService" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><SampleItem><Id>1</Id><StringValue>Hello</StringValue></SampleItem></ArrayOfSampleItem>
```

but it displays the following

```
1Hello
```

EDIT

And here is what is returned via fiddler

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 222
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 16 Aug 2010 19:56:27 GMT

<ArrayOfSampleItem xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/InmoCasaService" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><SampleItem><Id>1</Id><StringValue>Hello</StringValue></SampleItem></ArrayOfSampleItem>
```

**EDIT**

Now i have this... but still the same problem.. Look at the content type

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 226
Content-Type: application/xml
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 17 Aug 2010 06:09:14 GMT

<ArrayOfSampleItem xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/InmoCasaService" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><SampleItem><Id>1</Id><StringValue>He4444llo</StringValue></SampleItem></ArrayOfSampleItem>
```

Comment: What is the content type you are returning?

Comment: I have updated my question with info from fiddler also includes content type

Answer (score 1):

It's because Firefox is trying to render the file as HTML, as it is being told by the `Content-Type: text/html` header. And HTML browser should ignore unknown tags.

You want your server to return `Content-Type: application/xml`. I don't know how to configure IIS to do this, but the easiest way may be to name the file with the `.xml` extension, if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks for the comment... Well i have managed to change the content-type but everything is still the same... I will update my question with the fiddler headers etc

Comment: data:application/xml,<ArrayOfSampleItem ... </ArrayOfSampleItem> displays the XML tree when I try it. (I didn't paste in the whole XML because it confused Stack Overflow.) So it should work as an XML file, or served as shown.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, it turned out to be one of my plugins (Wappalyzer). Reading around, I think there are a few plugins that do this (Firebug included).

Disabling it and restarting Firefox fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is part of the magic that may help:

In your javascript, let's say you have a string of XML -- no matter how it got there -- like this:

```
var myXMLDoc = "<?xml version='1.0' ?><snarg><floof>42</floof></snarg>";
```

If you jam this into the current document, (or a new window), as is like this:

```
document.write (myXMLDoc);
```

Then browser will treat it as HTML, and you won't get the lovely XML tree diagram in Firefox.
But, if you preceed your document with magic that tells the browser how to interpret it:

```
document.write ("data:text/xml," + myXMLDoc);
```

Then you will kick Firefox into interpreting as XML and get the way cool tree diagram.

Answer (score 0):

Also it may not render in FF because you dont have xml full structure including header (not the http header, they seems fine) and encoding informations.

Comment: THanks, In Internet Explorer there is no issue.. What am i missing exactly then? My xml that is being returned is above in my question and it has a xmlns and is valid xml.

Comment: Try adding XML declaration at the beginning of the file: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>`